# Connection String on IP

Tags: asp.net, ip, connection-string

i have a problem with my connection string... i want to connect to 172.16.0.253,8887 but i cannot access it in ASP.NET but I can access it in SQL SERVER... what seems to be the problem with my script

code:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DBCS"
     connectionString="Data Source=172.16.0.253,8887; database = webloan; User ID=sa;         Password=12345; integrated security = SSPI"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: You've indicated SSPI, but also provided a username and password? Try `telnet 172.16.0.253 8887` to see if the sql `ip/port` is accessible from your asp server, and also make sure you connection string is in your root `web.config` (not a referenced assembly, if applicable). If the server is SqlExpress, you'll need to enable IP and open it up for remote access.

Comment: thanks for the reply... i already got it... I just removed the SSPI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should use your database user credential not 'sa'

Answer (score 1):

correct your user id and password. please correct to enter your user control panel username(user Id) and password